# Is it possible to use Github Pages using React without using create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github

I have an app that I would like to serve to Github Pages, It's nothing special just an API fetch APP that displays some data. However, I didn't use create-react-app, I built it from the ground up.

I've been interested in displaying it to some of my friends to help them with their coding and to actually use something that was built, however I've never tackled this problem and wanted to know if it was even possible

Comment: When I mean from the ground up, I npm installed all dependencies and config them, webpack babel etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploying a React Webpack app (not created with create-react-app) to Github pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42545439/deploying-a-react-webpack-app-not-created-with-create-react-app-to-github-page)

Comment: Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684532/trying-to-push-webpack-to-gh-pages) might be helpful.